# Python- Invalid Syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, syntax

I'm getting an invalid syntax error in the final variable. I don't see what the problem is, I think my indentation is correct, can tell me what I am doing wrong? I'm trying to make a simple python xor program.

```
msg='To use this decimal to binary converter tool, you should type a decimal value like 308 into the left field below, and then hit the Convert button. This way you can convert up to 19 decimal characters (max. value of 9223372036854775807) to binary value.'
key='ab'

encrypt=[]
decrypt=[]
count=0

for i in msg:
    if count>=len(key):
          count=0

    encrypt.append(ord(i)^ord(key[count]))

    count+=1

count=0
print(encrypt)

for i in encrypt:

    if count>=len(key):
          count=0

    count+=1      
    decrypt.append(i^ord(key[count])

final=''.join(chr(e) for e in decrypt)
print(final)
```

Comment: Rather than posting a screenshot, post your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see *dubious* error messages in places that d*on't make sense*, ***count your parentheses!***

In you case, you missed a closing parentheses when calling the `ord` function:

```
decrypt.append(i ^ ord(key[count]))
```